# Is there a way to redirect (render) a window to a "memory display"?

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi, vdi

I want to make a windows application whose GUI will be streamed to another device (allowing remote control). The point is that I'm not willing to rely on creating Windows Sessions to isolate the GUI I/O's (1)

To achieve this, I started observing some existing solutions that are able to enable remote access using this premise to see if I could get a clue about where to start.

One of these solution is [Winflector](http://www.winflector.com/) (BTW: it is free up to 2 connections).

I got interested in this solution because it seems (I'm guessing) it detects only the repainted regions. What I took from my observations are that:

- While the streamed application is "invisibly" running locally in the same session I'm logged in (it shows the application process in my task manager), the application window seems not to be created anyhow - at least [Inspect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can't get any window information/handle of the application process - It looks like sort of a "GUI StdOut Redirection".
- Apparently, no additional [Desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is created;
- Also apparently, no [Mirror Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is installed;
- Using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals//bb896653.aspx), I found out Winflector adds some thread's to the original application process. I suspect it is about the GUI redirection (by the thread's names);
- The application is started by the Winflector server - that is, it has control about the CreateProcess arguments.

What is the most likely technique to be used in this case?

- Windows Hook?
- Windows Messages interception?
- Special Display Driver?
- Sort of [Memory Device Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Where should I start researching to get a similar approach? Any open source project regarding this subject would also be very welcomed.

PS: By my programming experience, this is sort of a whole "new world" - sorry if my questions are redundant/obvious/non-sense.

> (1) That is, this application could be spawned, streamed and interact
>   with the remote client using the same session which a local user is
>   already logged in, without conflicting the IO (like a regular VNC
>   would do, for example). *PS:* At this moment, I'm focusing only at the
>   **output**.

Comment: Have you looked at [Remote Desktop Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb892075(v=vs.85).aspx) - there's a pile of built-in code there that handles all that, and does it securely.

Comment: @EricBrown: Thank's for your reference. I'll take a look at that.